# NX on a centos server and connect a windows 7

Tags: centos, ssh-agent, nx

I have a centOS 6.5 server

```
cat /etc/*elease
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

I tried to install the NX on it using this document https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/FreeNX

This is how I install it because the latest package was moved from the web

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm
yum install freenx-server nxagent


yum install opennx
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.aol.com
 * extras: chicago.gaminghost.co
 * nux-dextop: li.nux.ro
 * updates: centos.pymesolutionsweb.com
Setting up Install Process
Package opennx-0.16-724.el6.centos.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Then I install it on a Desktop environment (windows 7) on the machine in order to run the remote session. I installed the opnenx using the following link http://opennx.net/

I set it up as it is explained here

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/FreeNX

Then I try to connect but it always gives me the following message

[image]

what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [x2go](http://www.x2go.org) instead. It uses the same technology (but is incompatible to FreeNX).